# Blender AttributeError: 'PreferenceView' object has no attribute 'use_international_fonts'

Tags: python, add-on, error, command-line

I am at intermediate level in Blender and i recently came across Groove 3D. So, I downloaded and installed it. But when I enable the add-on it displays " Error(see console) " under Preferences option.
When i open the console, I see the following message:
AttributeError: 'PreferenceView' object has no attribute 'use_international_fonts'
Please help me solve this immediately.

[image: snapshot]P.S: I am not very familiar with python or coding in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the version of Groove3D that you're using hasn't been updated for Blender 2.83. This Blender version introduced a change to the Python API. The handling of languages and translation were adjusted by:

- https://developer.blender.org/D7210
- https://developer.blender.org/rB968619d03626c7e4d92d4cb383ac304b72595af3

As a consequence the `use_international_fonts` mentioned in the error message no longer exists.

Therefore, I would suggest you contact the developer, in case they aren't aware of this change. In the meantime you could use the add-on in Blender 2.82.

Comment: Thanks @Robert_Gützkow